# Why is my form not working using POST method?

Tags: php, forms

I have written the below HTML code:

```
  <form action="index.php" method="POST">    
      <input type="text" name="title" required>
      <input type="text" name="brief_text" required>
      <textarea name="text" required></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
  </form>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $brief_text = $_POST['brief_text'];
  $text = $_POST['text'];
  $blog_cat_id = $_POST['blog_cat_id'];

  if($title AND $brief_text AND $text AND $blog_cat_id){
    $insert_blog = "insert into blog values ('','$title','$brief_text','$text','$blog_cat_id',NOW())";
    $run_insertion = mysqli_query($con, $insert_blog);

    if($run_insertion){
      echo "Blog has been added!";
     }
    else{
      echo "Error adding blog!!!";
    }
 }
 else{
   echo "All fields are required!";
 }
}
else{
echo "GOODBYE";
}

?>
```

Every time I refresh the page, it only shows the form and "GOODBYE" and does not even insert the data into database table.
Help me out please.

Comment: change `$_POST['add_blog']` to `$_POST['add']`

Comment: i did, but not working

Comment: what is `blog_cat_id`..? its not in HTML Form

Comment: change ($title AND $brief_text AND $text AND $blog_cat_id)  to  ($title && $brief_text && $text && $blog_cat_id). There is no AND operator in php

Comment: i just removed it from html, its a select tag with name blog_cat_id. its the categories of blogs in select tag.

Comment: my first if statement is not woking, this one is second if statement ---- ($title AND $brief_text AND $text AND $blog_cat_id)

Comment: well you need to keep it, that is what causing error in SQL Query.. you can do `print_r($_POST)` below `require_once` to check which values are coming through post.

Comment: tried with print_r($_POST), its printing something ARRAY()

Comment: @aat There IS an 'and' logical operator in Php.  Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: i have changed them to &&

Comment: What happens when you 'submit' your form?

Comment: Thanx @Progrock  for the info. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @SubhamChakraborty your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Please use prepared statements.

Comment: @Progrock it does nothing

Comment: Try replacing your $run_insertion line temporarily to `$run_insertion = true;`  If you get the text 'Blog has been added!', start looking into debugging your database insert.

Comment: $_REQUEST['add']

Comment: i have figured it out. thanks all. it was a javascript error on textarea tag

Comment: I didn't see any javascript in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes,

1) should be: `$_POST['add']` instead of `$_POST['add_blog']`

2) don't have `$_POST['blog_cat_id']` as not in form

**EDIT**
Copied your code and made some changes:

**code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    print_r($_POST);
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $brief_text = $_POST['brief_text'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $blog_cat_id = $_POST['blog_cat_id'];

    if($title AND $brief_text AND $text AND $blog_cat_id){
        echo "inside condition";
        $insert_blog = "insert into blog values ('','$title','$brief_text','$text','$blog_cat_id',NOW())";
        $run_insertion = mysqli_query($con, $insert_blog);

        if($run_insertion){
          echo "Blog has been added!";
      }
      else{
          echo "Error adding blog!!!";
      }
  }
  else{
     echo "All fields are required!";
 }
}
else{
    echo "GOODBYE";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">    
      <input type="text" name="title" required>
      <input type="text" name="brief_text" required>
      <input type="text" name="blog_cat_id" required>
      <textarea name="text" required></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
  </form>
```

**output**

```
Array ( [title] => test [brief_text] => test [blog_cat_id] => 1 [text] => testing [add] => Add ) 

inside condition
```

Now, check your query if doesn't work.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its $_POST['add'] , but every time same problem. the first if statement is not working

Comment: yes, you have corrected that, now need to check for `blog_cat_id` which is not there in form , so as per your `if` statement it will not go into your insert code

Comment: @JigarShah name is `add` not `Add`. `Add` is value attribute of `submit`.

Comment: @SubhamChakraborty, updated code , replace with your code and you will be inside condition where you can insert record

Comment: i have figured it out. thanks all. it was a javascript error on textarea tag

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong, columns are not specified and you are open to sql injection you should learn to use parameterized query. but for this time you can use the following.

Try this:

**htmlcode**

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">    
  <input type="text" name="title" required>
  <input type="text" name="brief_text" required>
  <input type="text" name="blog_cat_id" required>
  <textarea name="text" required></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $brief_text = $_POST['brief_text'];
  $text = $_POST['text'];
  $blog_cat_id = $_POST['blog_cat_id'];

  if($title AND $brief_text AND $text AND $blog_cat_id){
    $insert_blog = "insert into blog('col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6') values ('','$title','$brief_text','$text','$blog_cat_id',NOW())";
    $run_insertion = mysqli_query($con, $insert_blog);

    if($run_insertion){
      echo "Blog has been added!";
     }
    else{
      echo "Error adding blog!!!";
    }
 }
 else{
   echo "All fields are required!";
 }
}
?>
```

**Note :** `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 and col6` will be your column name.

Comment: i have changed the code to if(isset($_POST['add'])), still same problem

Comment: What did you get? Is there any undefined warning?

Comment: nope, before clicking on Add, it show GOODBYE everytime

Comment: It's showing a goodbye message to you because your else block executed. `if(isset($_POST['add']))` it will check only when you click the submit button else goodbye will be display. It's not a error.

Comment: so what should be solution

Comment: What do you want to achive? Remove else part it doesn't make sense.

Comment: buddy it still not calling if(isset($_POST['add'])) statement

Comment: what did you get? you have to tell us buddy we can't help without specification.

Comment: @SubhamChakraborty Try the updated code. and let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: @AnkitSingh you may omit column names for SQL inserts if you provide values for all relevant columns.

Comment: Thanks @Progrock I didn't know about this.

Comment: i have figured it out. thanks all. it was a javascript error on textarea tag

Comment: Good to hear:).

Answer (score 0):

Is it still showing 'GOODBYE' now you've changed

```
$_POST['add_blog']
```

to

```
$_POST['add']
```

when you click submit?

Comment: Where have you put that php code? Is it inside index.php?

Comment: yes, first i had put it into another file and called the file name is form action, there was same problem

Comment: If the PHP and the HTML are in the same file try setting the form action to just action=""

Comment: And the first if statement will only be true if you're actually clicking on the submit button, refreshing the page won't define the post variable

Comment: buddy it still not calling if(isset($_POST['add'])) statement

Comment: @MattWills it will populate the post variable if you are refreshing/re-submitting the POST data (or rather refreshing after a submission).

Comment: Better to test against this `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` for a form POST, otherwise you'll trigger undefined index notices.

Comment: i have figured it out. thanks all. it was a javascript error on textarea tag